# How to display a checkbox field using lightning-datatable?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

[[image: I have data of having a Boolean field. i want to show that in lightning-datatable as a Check box instead of Utility:check. like show in Image.2]

I have data of having a Boolean field. i want to show that in lightning-datatable as a Check box instead of Utility:check. like show in Image

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement "instead of Utility:check". Have you tried the `type: 'boolean'` of the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) and you are not happy with it?

Comment: i tried but by default it showing "Utility:check". i want it as Check box as how in image.

Comment: Please add the code that you currently use to your question.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the checkbox to be checked if the Boolean is true? and uncheck if the boolean is false? When you fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard data table component. If you use a `boolean` type, it will show just the icon. The actual checkbox is only available at the left side, row-level, for selecting a row in the table.

Here's a screenshot of the corner of a data table component with the first column having the `boolean` type assigned to it:

[image: checkbox in table example]

Particularly I don't see the absolute **need** for changing this. If you do, however, need to use an actual checkbox, then you might need to find or build yourself a custom data table component.

Some good reasons not to pursue what you are trying to do include the difficulty of building a custom data table component, the need to maintain third-party code on your org if you do find an open source solution for that, spending money on a paid solution (if it exists) and finally: this goes against the design guidelines that Salesforce itself promotes in its design system.